# JS script doesn't work in a Thymeleaf template

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add a default 404 error page to my Spring app, and I thought it would be nice to add an animate template like that: https://codepen.io/wikyware-net/pen/xywexE

The whole idea is a validation of form and redirection to the error page, if it fails.
Basically, redirection works fine, but the problem I have is I can not make the JS part running (the tost doesn't pop up :-/)...

Here's how my error page looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ooops... Something went wrong!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Создание адаптивного сайта"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/error.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/static/js/error.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ag-page-404">
    <div class="ag-toaster-wrap">
        <div class="ag-toaster">
            <div class="ag-toaster_back"></div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_front">
                <div class="js-toaster_lever ag-toaster_lever"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_toast-handler">
                <div class="ag-toaster_shadow"></div>
                <div class="js-toaster_toast ag-toaster_toast js-ag-hide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <canvas id="canvas-404" class="ag-canvas-404"></canvas>
        <img class="ag-canvas-404_img"
             src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SochavaAG/example-mycode/master/pens/404-error-smoke-from-toaster/images/smoke.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a th:href="@{/home}" target="_blank" class="btn-primary">Go back</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Both CSS and JS code I use, is included in the template I attached at the very beginning.

Here's also the snapshot of the project's resources structure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
What are best practices in importing such a HTML template into a Spring Boot/Thymeleaf project?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind regards,
Matthew

---

### EDIT:

So I changed my html page to that form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ooops... Something went wrong!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Создание адаптивного сайта"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/error.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ag-page-404">
    <div class="ag-toaster-wrap">
        <div class="ag-toaster">
            <div class="ag-toaster_back"></div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_front">
                <div class="js-toaster_lever ag-toaster_lever"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_toast-handler">
                <div class="ag-toaster_shadow"></div>
                <div class="js-toaster_toast ag-toaster_toast js-ag-hide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <canvas id="canvas-404" class="ag-canvas-404"></canvas>
        <img class="ag-canvas-404_img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SochavaAG/example-mycode/master/pens/404-error-smoke-from-toaster/images/smoke.png">
    </div>
</div>
    <div>
        <a th:href="@{/home}" target="_blank" class="btn-primary">Go back</a>
    </div>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/error.js}"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
```

Plus, I also updated my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'pl.mpas'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.3.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '3.3.6'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap-datepicker', version: '1.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.webjars.bower', name: 'jquery', version: '3.5.1'
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.apache.struts:struts2-core:2.3.16.1')
    providedCompile('javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1')
    providedCompile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0')
}
```

Thanks to that, I no longer see any errors in the browser's console.
However... JS still doesn't work as expected. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files structure looks good. you have added your js file in error page by

```
 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/static/js/error.js}"></script>
```

but I don't think you need to mention static in your source URL for JS, Change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/error.js}"></script>
```

also please add the below dependencies in your pom.xml for jQuery and Bootstrap

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

change your error.html file as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ooops... Something went wrong!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Создание адаптивного сайта"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/error.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ag-page-404">
    <div class="ag-toaster-wrap">
        <div class="ag-toaster">
            <div class="ag-toaster_back"></div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_front">
                <div class="js-toaster_lever ag-toaster_lever"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_toast-handler">
                <div class="ag-toaster_shadow"></div>
                <div class="js-toaster_toast ag-toaster_toast js-ag-hide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <canvas id="canvas-404" class="ag-canvas-404"></canvas>
        <img class="ag-canvas-404_img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SochavaAG/example-mycode/master/pens/404-error-smoke-from-toaster/images/smoke.png">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/error.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

now it will work fine. Let me know if any doubt.
Refer:https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-with-jquery-and-bootstrap-web-jars

Comment: Hi Ajit, thanks for your answer!

So, I applied your suggestions, but there's still something wrong with jQuery apparently, as I still got errors in the browser's console.
Is it possible that I need newer dependencies than the ones which you sent?

Comment: Please check once, Because the same is working for me.

Comment: I checked once again, unfortunately - still the same... :-/
I get: "Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined"...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

---

Change your JavaScript reference for your `error.js` script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/error.js}"></script>
```

There is no need to include the `/static` portion of the URL.

---

Also, have you included jQuery in the page? For example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

You will see an error in the browser's console if jQuery is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your JavaScript reference in your HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/error.js" type="text/javascript" th:href="@{/error.js}">
```

Comment: Hi Chandra,

Nooope, that actually made things even worse... :) Nor CSS or JS is displayed properly after that change.

Answer (score 0):

All right guys, I finally made it running. In my case the problem was a lack of jQuery's script tag in html's head section. I used Google's CDN hosting:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So the final, working version of my page looks as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ooops... Something went wrong!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Создание адаптивного сайта"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/error.css}"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ag-page-404">
    <div class="ag-toaster-wrap">
        <div class="ag-toaster">
            <div class="ag-toaster_back"></div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_front">
                <div class="js-toaster_lever ag-toaster_lever"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-toaster_toast-handler">
                <div class="ag-toaster_shadow"></div>
                <div class="js-toaster_toast ag-toaster_toast js-ag-hide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <canvas id="canvas-404" class="ag-canvas-404"></canvas>
        <img class="ag-canvas-404_img"
             src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SochavaAG/example-mycode/master/pens/404-error-smoke-from-toaster/images/smoke.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a th:href="@{/home}" target="_blank" class="btn-primary">Go back</a>
</div>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/error.js}"></script>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks again for your help! Cheers!